# removeClass in timeout not working

Tags: javascript

**I SOLVED THE PROBLEM**

**I added a timeout function on the next line where I empty the array.**

I am new a javascript and this is my code

The array is an array with spans.

```
            pickedArray[0].removeClass('show');
            pickedArray[1].removeClass('show');
```

and this works but too fast.

However when I do like this

```
        setTimeout(function(){  
            pickedArray[0].removeClass('show');
            pickedArray[1].removeClass('show');

        }, 100);
```

I get an error "Cannot read property 'removeClass' of undefined"

How Can I correct this?

Thanks

Here is my code, I know it's messy but I just want it to work.

```
var activeCards = 0;
var firstPick = 0;
var secondPick = 0;
var pickedArray = [];

$('.card').click(function() {
    console.log('I was clicked.' + ' ' + activeCards);
    activeCards++;
    var span = $(this).find('span');
    pickedArray.push(span);
    console.log(span.text())
    span.addClass('show')
    if (activeCards == 1) {
        firstPick = span.text();
    } else {
        secondPick = span.text();
        activeCards = 0;
        if (firstPick == secondPick) {
            console.log(firstPick + " " + secondPick)
            setTimeout(function() {
                alert("You got a match");
            }, 100);
            pickedArray[0].parent().addClass('matched');
            pickedArray[1].parent().addClass('matched');

        } else {


            setTimeout(function() {
                  pickedArray[0].removeClass('show');
                  pickedArray[1].removeClass('show');;

            }, 100);

        }
        pickedArray = []
    }
});
```

Comment: Where have you declared the arrays?

Comment: not in any brackets. just in my script tag.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: You need to provide a real [mcve]. The problem is most likely caused by something modifying the array between you calling `setTimeout` and the time out resolving, but the tiny fragment of code you've supplied doesn't demonstrate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediately after calling `setTimeout` you say:

```
pickedArray = []
```

which overwrites it with an empty array.

100ms later, `pickedArray[0]` is therefore undefined.

You could pass the array to your function as an argument:

```
setTimeout(function(myArray) {
      myArray[0].removeClass('show');
      myArray[1].removeClass('show');;

}.bind(null, pickedArray), 100);
```

Comment: Thank you, I realized that this is the issue and fixed it. Thanks for your help.